# opencv haar files returning too many facial features

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, haar-classifier

I am trying to detect Elon Musks facial features. Right now it is sort of able to but I am detecting too many eye, nose, and mouth features. I'm not sure how I can fix this to only find one set of each.

I am using the haar files provided by opencv's [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) and for nose and mouth I found some haar files somewhere online.

```
haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
haarcascade_eye.xml
```

haar files

```
class Filterize(object):
    def __init__(self, filterpath):
        self.filterpath = filterpath
        self.haarpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'haar')
        self.face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(self.haarpath, 'face.xml'))
        self.eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(self.haarpath, 'eye.xml'))
        self.nose_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(self.haarpath, 'nose.xml'))
        self.mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(self.haarpath, 'mouth.xml'))

    def get_filter_facial_features(self):
        filter = cv2.imread(self.filterpath)
        grayscale_filter = cv2.cvtColor(filter, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face = self.face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale_filter, 1.3, 5)
        for x, y, w, h in face:
            cv2.rectangle(filter, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            roi_gray = grayscale_filter[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            roi_color = filter[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            eyes = self.eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.3, 5)
            nose = self.nose_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.3, 5)
            mouth = self.mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.3, 5)
            for eye_x, eye_y, eye_w, eye_h in eyes:
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (eye_x, eye_y), (eye_x + eye_w, eye_y + eye_h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            for nose_x, nose_y, nose_w, nose_h in nose:
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (nose_x, nose_y), (nose_x + nose_w, nose_y + nose_h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            for mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h in mouth:
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (mouth_x, mouth_y), (mouth_x + mouth_w, mouth_y + mouth_h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.imwrite('face.png', filter)
```

To create the photo:

```
a = Filterize(filterpath)
a.get_filter_facial_features()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line here:

```
face = self.face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale_filter, 1.3, 5)
```

You pass in the following parameters available (taken from [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale)):

> Parameters:
>
> - cascade – Haar classifier cascade (OpenCV 1.x API only). It can be    loaded from XML or YAML file using Load(). When the cascade is not
>     needed anymore, release it using
>     cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(&cascade).
> - image – Matrix of the type    CV_8U containing an image where objects are detected. objects –    Vector of rectangles where each
>     rectangle contains the detected    object.
> - scaleFactor – Parameter specifying how much the image size is    reduced at each image scale.
> - minNeighbors – Parameter specifying how    many neighbors each candidate rectangle should have to retain it.
> - flags – Parameter with the same meaning for an old cascade as in the    function cvHaarDetectObjects. It is not used for a new cascade.
> - minSize – Minimum possible object size. Objects smaller than that are    ignored.
> - maxSize – Maximum possible object size. Objects larger than    that are ignored.

What this function does is detect all the features it can with defined boundaries. I would suggest you need to play around with these values until the amount of rectangles comes to an acceptable amount.

In fact maxSize looks like a good start, as you have smaller rectangles for each detection